# How do I get URLs from hyperlinks in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a column of cells with hyperlinks (to web addresses) and I need their URLs to be regular text. Is there a way to extract the URLs from hyperlinks?
Example:
Cell says: "CLICKME"
Links to: www.www.com

I want the cell to only say www.www.com.
I explored the paste special features and didn't find any answers there. I know how to replace the display text with the URL for a single cell, but my table has 700+ such cells I need this for and can't spend all day doing it one cell at a time. Suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy with some [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx) -

```
Sub test()
    Dim link As Hyperlink
    For Each link In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        link.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = link.Address
    Next
End Sub
```

Run this and all the addresses will appear in the cell to the right of the hyperlink.